# Addition of cyclohexanone to indole with MeONa and MeOH

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I need to find this reaction mechanism and i have run out of ideas. I have tried using -OMe on both indole and on cyclohexanone in order to create an enolate but i cant think of anything else. Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: With the tag reaction-mechanism, the title Reaction mechanism brings literally zero additional info about the post. // A good question title should be unique, resembling a magazine article headline or a book title, in plain text, optionally formulated as a question. Avoid click baits, titles saying too much or too little.

Comment: Basically an enamine reaction

Comment: it seems like enamine reaction but the N doesnt get attached to any carbon. Am i mistaken?

Comment: The N remains unsubstituted.

Comment: As to your comment that " N doesn't get attached to any carbon", neither does nitrogen get attached to carbon in enamine reactions.

Comment: Is this a real reaction or an example from an exam paper? I can find no literature that reports such a reaction pathway under the reported conditions

Comment: it is an exam question. i couldn't find any citations either, that's why i made this post. I just made up a mechanism and i m still not sure if it is right

Comment: @user55119 but it does, doesnt it ? a similar reaction i found was stork enamine alkylation

Comment: With allylic halides initial attachment is to nitrogen, but then they rearrange to carbon. It is possible to write a base catalyzed mechanism for your reaction. If I were going to try to do the reaction, I would use an acid catalyst. I looked up this reaction between indole and cyclohexanone on chemical abstracts, but I couldn’t find it.

Comment: okay thank you for the information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Comments have pretty much ruled out the existence of this reaction in the chemical literature. Like many exam questions the proposed reaction is conceptually possible but that doesn't mean that it occurs. The reaction for indole itself (**1b**), in principle, would be catalytic in base in that alkoxide is regenerated. Your indole (**1a**) requires stoichiometric base to neutralize the carboxylic acid in addition to the catalytic amount of base required to effect the reaction. In practice, an excess of base would normally be employed.
Indole (**1b**) has a [pKa of ~21](https://www.scripps.edu/baran/heterocycles/Essentials1-2009.pdf) while methanol's [pKa is 15.5](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01489a008). This means that the concentration of resonance stabilized anion **2** is quite low. However, it is a better nucleophile than indole itself. Any addition of the nitrogen of **2** to cyclohexanone (**3**) will be unproductive because the reverse reaction is its only option. Addition of the carbon site to **3** leads to protonation of the alkoxide and regeneration of the indole nucleus as shown in structure **4**. During the course of these steps either **4** or **5** may be protonated and deprotonated. Species **5** effects  elimination of hydroxide affording **6**, which upon vinylogous deprotonation leads on to the final product **8** via **7**. *continued*

[image]

The foregoing reaction is a case of a strong nucleophile (**2**) and a decent electrophile (**3**). What about the use of a strong electrophile (**9**) and a decent nucleophile (**1**)? An acid-catalyzed route is less problematic having the [Vilsmeier-Haack formylation of indole](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/vilsmeier-reaction.shtm) as a precedent. Accordingly, species **10**, which is formed from protonated cyclohexanone **9** and indole **1**, aromatizes to indole **11**. Acid-catalyzed loss of water from **12** affords **8** via **13**.
If I were setting out to accomplish this reaction, I would certainly opt for the acid-catalyzed route.

[image]

Comment: thank you a lot for your reply! I hadnt thought about pKa, but i gave a similar mechanism for the exam so its nice to see that my thoughts are okay, at least for the sake of examination. I would definitely use acidic conditions if i were doing this in a lab